# Why is Spring Security not properly reading my Auth0 OAuth permissions using hasAuthority?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, access-token, auth0

I have the following…

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/**")
                        ).hasAuthority("SCOPE_read:actuators")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties, @Value("${auth0.audience}") String audience) {
        /*
         * By default, Spring Security does not validate the "aud" claim of the token,
         * to ensure that this token is
         * indeed intended for our app. Adding our own validator is easy to do:
         */

        String issuerUri = properties.getJwt().getIssuerUri();
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuerUri);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = AudienceValidator.of(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
```

And the following config…

```yaml
auth0:
  audience: ...
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ...
```

I am trying to call the endpoint with curl http://localhost:8080/actuator -v -H "Authorization: Bearer ..." and curl http://localhost:8080/actuator -v -H "Authorization: OAuth ..."

I have confirmed the access token has

```json
{
  "iss": "...",
  "sub": "...",
  "aud": [
    "...",
    "..."
  ],
  "iat": ...,
  "exp": ...,
  "azp": "...",
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "permissions": [
    "read:actuators"
  ]
}
```

The aud and iss match but when I go to the site I get a 403. If I make it permit-all then it works fine.

What am I missing here?

I also tried to add this but the same issue...

```
.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                        .jwt((jwt) ->jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder()))
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable resource server configuration for access token to be used when building the security context.

You also need a `Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>` to convert the content of a private claim into Spring authorities. `JwtAuthenticationConverter` is the default implementation for this interface and configurable to some extent (will work if you want to use only one claim directly under root node, which seems to be your case for now). Just expose a bean of that type with overriden configuration to read the `permissions` claim.

You can find samples in [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials), all work with Auth0 (as well as Keycloak, and Amazon Cognito).

Comment: I will take a look at your examples thank you but I am seeing the authorities seem to be getting mapped incorrectly given their example and are instead the scopes...

["SCOPE_openid","SCOPE_profile","SCOPE_email"]* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact. Instead of the permissions suggested here https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5/interactive#create-the-api-controller so my guess is that converter will map the permissions properly?

Comment: Also why is that class also not in the above linked example

Comment: The default converter uses scope claim as source for authorities and adds `SCOPE_` prefix, reason for me writing in my answer that you have to provide your own (which is not done in your question and explains why you get scopes as authorities ...).

Comment: Any idea why they don't mention that in the link

Comment: Also do you happen to have a simpler example that doesn't have a lot of abstraction? I am trying to copy the code like what I see here https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/6861fbf786528752b83111e6dcbf6d19ac1cb9ac/samples/tutorials/bff/README.md?plain=1#L554 but I am going down a rabbit hole of the custom classes used

Comment: Actually, they do: look at the note at the end of [section 5](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5/interactive#configure-the-resource-server)

Comment: The simplest samples are on the [main readme](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/6861fbf786528752b83111e6dcbf6d19ac1cb9ac/README.MD#11-usage) but it implies using "my" starter ([make sure to read this first](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#0-risks-of-using-this-libs-and-mitigations)).

Comment: That section seems to contradict itself "By default, Spring Security creates a GrantedAuthority for each scope in the scope claim of the JWT. This scope enables using the hasAuthority("SCOPE_read:messages")" but it creates read:messages as an entry in the permission claim. It does when you know what you are looking for I suppose give you an answer. Thanks to your help I did get it to work so thank you very much and I appreciate all the time you spent on the example. I am going to post a more concise example as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The bean it was missing (Just for Auth0) is this

```java
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("permissions");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
```

The permission can be extracted to a application property if your provider uses something else but for auth0 it will always be permissions.

More information can be found in the official [Spring Security site here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction)

Comment: Congratulations, you applied exactly what I answered: look at the interface implemented by the `JwtAuthenticationConverter` you expose as a bean and compare it to the interface in my answer.

Comment: Yup I see that so maybe they just introduced something similar to your thing. Anyway thanks again for the direction.

Comment: Actually, `JwtAuthenticationConverter` is the default `Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>` implementation by Spring Security. It is configurable to some extent, but not as much as what I provide (and not from just properties): for instance it won't work if you need to use more than one claim as source for authorities or if the claim is nested (like you could need some day as Auth0 custom claims are nested in a domain you define like `{"c4-soft.com": {"roles": [] }}`).

Comment: Updated the answer to be a little clearer and upvoted your answer which complements it.

Comment: See my issue here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555638/spring-boot-not-reading-auth0-permissions-although-i-created-a-customjwtauthenti

Comment: Neither him nor I use Okta starter. Look at the package of the bean you try to override...