# Spring boot not reading Auth0 permissions although I created a customJwtAuthenticationConverter

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth, auth0

In my Spring boot project I'm using Auth0

I need to read the permissions from the Auth0 jwt token and then use them to evaluate hasAuthority.

Despite all my effort, I'm not able to read from permissions, although I created a customJwtAuthenticationConverter to do so

I jave the following JWT token (I removed some chars so no sensible data is shared here):

```
{
  "iss": "https://dev-hxo7qtywv.eu.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "google-oauth2|10344498554237",
  "aud": [
    "https://test/api",
    "https://dev-hxo7qtywv.eu.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 17010717,
  "exp": 17019317,
  "azp": "dv1rEpS37p9jaGIPXO0S5fnjMh",
  "scope": "openid profile email offline_access",
  "permissions": [
    "read:admin",
    "SCOPE_read:admin"
  ]
}
```

This is part of the content of my SecurityFilterChain class

```
@Bean
  public JwtAuthenticationConverter customJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("permissions");
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
  }
```

And

```
      .requestMatchers("/api/test/admin").hasAuthority("read:admin")
```

And

```
http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtAuthenticationConverter())));
```

I checked the authorities in the controller and I see the following:

```
Authority: SCOPE_openid
Authority: SCOPE_profile
Authority: SCOPE_email
Authority: SCOPE_offline_access
```

Any idea about why Spring boot it's not using my customJwtAuthenticationConverter?

Comment: Please give your full security configuration class. Maybe you just forgot to decorate it with `@Configuration`, or you're having another `SecurityFilterChain` bean hiding the resource server one, or whatever that we can't guess with what you just provide.

Comment: Also give your dependencie: the additional `SecurityFilterChain` hiding yours could come from a Spring Boot starter not backing off correctly when you provide with your own filter-chain.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. In the newest library you can configure it only in the following way (in application.yml)

```
okta:
    oauth2:
        groupsClaim: permissions
```